# How do I extend an existing popup window in SDL Tridion 2011?

Tags: cme, configuration, gui-extensions

I am trying to add some additional fields to the Link popup window which is opened when a user clicks "Hyperlink" in a rich text editor.

I would (ideally) like to replace Link.aspx in `Editors\Views\Popups\Link` with my own extendedLink.aspx page.

I have been looking at the `<extensions>` node in the config file (and numerous examples around the web):

```
<ext:editurls />
<ext:listdefinitions />
<ext:taskbars />
<ext:commands />
<ext:commandextensions/>
<ext:contextmenus/>
<ext:lists />
<ext:tabpages>
```

None of these seem like an obvious place to put an extension to an existing popup window.

Am I going about this all wrong? Should I be using JavaScript to extend the Hyperlink button, turn off the existing popup, and then provide my own?

Should I remove the button entirely and replace it with one that's identical?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of views has ExtendableArea functionality, in this areas you can simply embed your control and associate its initialization with any of the view events. Unfortunately Link popup is not that view.

From my practice, when I have to extend existing view which does not have any valid extensibility points, I`m using http://tridion.uibeardcore.com/2014/02/js-overwriting/ .

In this case you need to create extension where you have to override some of Tridion.Cme.Views.Link methods.

For instance in initialize method you can add creation of the controls which you want to add Such as button conntrol

```
var buttonNew = $controls.createControl("Tridion.Controls.Button", { text: "New Button", id: "buttonNew"});
```

Then appending its elements to the html element on the page.

```
this.properties.controls.BtnOk.getElement().parentNode.appendChild(buttonNew.getElement());
```